# How to create component dynamically with conditional templateUrl in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

My application needs to support customized HTML for the client so one component can have two options of **templateHtml**.

```
import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit, Input
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: '<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() name: string;

  @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) dynamicTemplate: any;

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
              private _injector: Injector,
              private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let myTemplateUrl = './hello.component.html';

    if (this.id % 2 == 1) { // if (haveCustomLayout) {
      myTemplateUrl = '../customlayout/hello.component.html';
    }

    const tmpCmp = Component({
      moduleId: "class_"+module.id, templateUrl: myTemplateUrl
    })(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });
    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule) // error here
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      });
  }
}
```

Here is the error from compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync:

> GET http://localhost:57630/hello.component.html 404 (Not Found)
>   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /hello.component.html

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw2bc7?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: I do not have a direct answer to your question.  But I am unsure why this is the approach we want to use.  If I were attempting to make your above example work, I would use either a) ngIf between two components one with one template and one with the other b) dynamicly instantiate one of two components one with one template and one with the other.  Either way, having a specific component that represents each of your html possibilities is I think a much cleaner approach to the problem.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved my problem by another way. I created a loader in npm to replace the templateUrl based in a json file.